# Google cloud app engine standard running Java 11 not handling HTTP if-modified-since header as expected

Tags: google-app-engine

Many of our web app's URLs are continually returning 304 with no body.

Testing on Chrome I can see the following header in all requests:

```
'if-modified-since: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:01 GMT'
```

App engine consistently returns 304, even for a newly deployed application.

I would expect this to retrun 200 with body content. These are not static URLs, so our backend code should be called to generate the content.

I've tried adding a Servlet filter which sets the Last-Modified header to something more recent but this seems to have no effect.

Can anyone tell me how to influence app-engine to return content correctly?

Comment: It seems like the client is sending a very old timestamp in the `if-modified-since` header, which is causing the server to always return a 304 response. This is likely because of some aggressive caching behavior on the client's side.

Comment: @Chanpols the client is Chrome and these are the standard cache headers sent.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this, the problem was due to appengine's cache mechanism.

When building an app, webpack sets all file timestamps to zero. When it is deployed on app-engine, all resource files (i.e. nothing that runs code) will be sent to Googles CDN. All requests for a resource are served from the CDN - and because all timestamps are zero, it cannot tell when a new version has been added, and returns an old file.

Google engineers suggested adding a flag that would set the timestamp for all files to the deployment time of the application, but this has not happened.

A quick fix, is to configure a Servlet path for the resource (i.e. your code must be run) and then load and return the file from the **local file system**. Do not use a ServletDispatcher to return the resource, as that will serve the cached version.